# nginx URL-rewrite dynamic for all subfolders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I am facing the following problem when migrating from apache to nginx:
When deploying a folder named "apps" including about 10 subfolders with zend framework 2 apps, I am not able to browse my zf-routes (http 404).

This happens because my htaccess is not read and my rewrite does not take place.

It would work when defining all projects in my nginx config but this is not very dynamic and all new projects would need a new entry while apache read the .htaccess in all folders and did it on itself.

Is there any nginx directive I did not find to accomplish this?

I am currently trying this codeblock:

```
location /apps/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }
```

I know this would cause nginx to check /apps/index.php instead of /apps/(projectname)/index.php - but I don't know how to change this.

Comment: why `location /apps` not `location /` ?

Comment: it is for our intranet webserver and our zend framework 2 apps are located under /apps/ in the vhost dir.

Comment: ok so add the `/apps` to the `root` not the `location`

Comment: this is not a solution because I would not be able to setup an other application outside "apps". I found a working solution (in my own answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
location /apps/(.*)/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /apps/(.*)/index.php?$args;
    }
```

This is the solution. I just missed the part before index.php.